# jetty-maven-plugin logback stops loggins after configuration is picked

Tags: java, jetty, slf4j, logback

I have issue regarding log4j logging. I am using logback and configuration is picked and seen in logs, but after that nothing goes to console or to file (logging.log file is created but empty). I am using org.eclipse.jetty jetty-maven-plugin version 9.2.13.v20150730.

Here is maven plugin config:

```
<configuration>
    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/</webAppSourceDirectory>
    <jettyXml>src/test/resources/jetty-http.xml</jettyXml>
    <jvmArgs>-Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:PermSize=96m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m</jvmArgs>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
    <webApp>
        <contextPath>/web-server</contextPath>
        <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
        <overrideDescriptor>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-web.xml</overrideDescriptor>
    </webApp>
    <contextXml>src/test/resources/jetty-env.xml</contextXml>
    <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
    <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
    <systemProperties>
        <systemProperty>
            <name>logback.configurationFile</name>
            <value>src/test/resources/logback-test.xml</value>
        </systemProperty>
    </systemProperties>
</configuration>
```

The only log I get from logback is:

```
logs from jetty starting before this line...
avg 19, 2015 10:37:00 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml]
10:37:00,763 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [src/test/resources/logback-test.xml] at [file:/home/matjaz/workspaces/andWspc/my-base/web-server/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml]
10:37:00,792 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
10:37:00,793 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
10:37:00,799 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
10:37:00,812 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
10:37:00,838 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
10:37:00,840 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [QUICK_LOG]
10:37:00,845 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
10:37:00,845 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[QUICK_LOG] - No TriggeringPolicy was set for the RollingFileAppender named QUICK_LOG
10:37:00,845 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[QUICK_LOG] - For more information, please visit http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#rfa_no_tp
10:37:00,846 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to DEBUG
10:37:00,846 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [QUICK_LOG] to Logger[ROOT]
10:37:00,846 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
10:37:00,846 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework.core level set to WARN
10:37:00,846 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework.beans level set to WARN
10:37:00,846 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework.context level set to WARN
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework.http level set to WARN
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.springframework.web level set to WARN
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.SQL level set to DEBUG
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.type level set to DEBUG
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.stat level set to DEBUG
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - org.hibernate.jdbc level set to DEBUG
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
10:37:00,847 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@269c62d0 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

avg 19, 2015 10:37:00 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web.server.xml]
logs from jetty starting after this line...
```

logback-test.xml configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="QUICK_LOG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logging.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} [%-10c] [%-8t] [%C{10}.%M\(\):%L] - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="QUICK_LOG" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>


    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <!--<level value="DEBUG" />-->
        <level value="warn" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <!--<level value="DEBUG" />-->
        <level value="warn" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <!--<level value="DEBUG" />-->
        <level value="warn" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework.http">
        <!--<level value="DEBUG" />-->
        <level value="warn" />
    </logger>
    <!-- below alternate between debug and info -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <!--<level value="DEBUG" />-->
        <level value="warn" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <!--<level value="warn" />-->
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <!--<level value="warn" />-->
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.stat">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <!--<level value="warn" />-->
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.jdbc">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <!--<level value="warn" />-->
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Any hint, direction or anything else is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Are you running tests, or why are you using `logback-test.xml`?

Comment: I'm running testing configuration, so it doesn't go into production. Would it help to move and rename file to main instead of test? I'm starting with command jetty:run.

Comment: Well, `logback-test.xml` is used for tests (not your tests, I mean `mvn test` tests). I'm not sure how it behaves if it's the only config file on the classpath, but that's something worth checking out.

Comment: Tried it but it is still the same. Moved to main and changed value in plugin. I guess it doesn't matter where I put it as I define it in systemProperty inside plugin so path is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah, I missed the explicit file. Logback is very good at finding its configs by itself, although it will log all found files and tell you which one it's using, too.

Comment: I had to explicitly tell where to pick it. If I remove sysProp it doesn't find it, nor logback.xml nor logback-test.xml (in main and test).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87366/discussion-between-matjaz-and-kayaman).

Comment: Probably because of the Jetty plugin. As a standalone war it'll go as far as look inside the library jars for any logback configs...